# Update column with part of the data from column of another table in another database with intermediate tables

Tags: mysql, database, sql-update

I have a table **Tab1** in database DB1:

```
col1    | col2
--------------
'abc-1' | 11
'abc-2' | 22
'abc-3' | 33
null    | 44
null    | 55
```

I want to update col1 column from this table with data from column col3 from another table (**Tab2**) in another database (DB2):

```
col3    | col4 | col5
---------------------
'abc-1' | 1    | 10
'abc-1' | 2    | 10
'abc-2' | 1    | 20
'abc-3' | 1    | 30
'abc-3' | 2    | 30
'abc-3' | 3    | 30
'abc-4' | 1    | 40
'abc-5' | 2    | 60
```

(Data in col1 always comes from col3 only.)

The tables are connected through two intermediate tables: DB1.**Tab3**:

```
col6      | col7
----------------
'abc-001' | 11
'abc-002' | 22
'abc-003' | 33
'abc-004' | 44
```

and DB2.**Tab4**:

```
col8 | col9
----------------
10   | 'abc-001'
20   | 'abc-002'
30   | 'abc-003'
40   | 'abc-004'
50   | 'abc-005'
```

Now, col3 values may repeat (while being identified by id value) and this is the tricky part. Assuming that all values that are missing in col1 do not repeat in col3, this is how I update the column:

```
update DB1.Tab1 as T1
        inner join
    DB1.Tab3 as T3 ON T3.col7 = T1.col2
        inner join
    DB2.Tab4 as T4 ON T4.col9 = T3.col6
        inner join
    DB2.Tab2 as T2 ON T2.col5 = T4.col8 
set 
    T1.col1 = T2.col3
where
    T1.col1 is null;
```

This also works for repeated values in general - but I only want to update col1 when col3 values do not repeat, that is, in this case with values abc-2, abc-4, abc-5. This is how I select single col3 values (relevant for update):

```
select 
    col3
from
    DB2.Tab2 as T2
        inner join
    DB2.Tab4 as T4 ON T2.col5 = T4.col8
        inner join
    DB1.Tab3 as T3 ON T4.col9 = T3.col6
        inner join
    DB1.Tab1 as T1 ON T3.col7 = T1.col2
where
    T1.col1 is null
        and T1.col2 is not null
group by col3
having count(*) = 1;
```

The question is: how do I update col1 with col3 only with col3 values that does not repeat?

---

EDIT. This almost works:

```
update DB1.Tab1 as T1,
    (select 
        col3
    from
        DB2.Tab2 as T2
    inner join DB2.Tab4 as T4 ON T2.col5 = T4.col8
    inner join DB1.Tab3 as T3 ON T4.col9 = T3.col6
    inner join DB1.Tab1 as T1 ON T3.col7 = T1.col2
    where
        T1.col1 is null
            and T1.col2 is not null
    group by col3
    having count(*) = 1) as T2d 
set 
    T1.col1 = T2d.col3
where
    T1.col1 is null;
```

but it updates all empty col1 values with only one col3 value - the first one resulting from the select query. I think there is something missing in the where clause but I cannot formulate an appropriate condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. The problem was quite complex but the answer turned out to be simple after thinking it through.

My `update` statement that almost worked was lacking an additional condition in `select` statement and `where` clause.

```
update DB1.Tab1 as T1,
    (select 
        col3, T1.col2 as T1c2
    from
        DB2.Tab2 as T2
    inner join DB2.Tab4 as T4 ON T2.col5 = T4.col8
    inner join DB1.Tab3 as T3 ON T4.col9 = T3.col6
    inner join DB1.Tab1 as T1 ON T3.col7 = T1.col2
    where
        T1.col1 is null
            and T1.col2 is not null
    group by col3
    having count(*) = 1) as T2d 
set 
    T1.col1 = T2d.col3
where
    T1.col1 is null
        and T1.col2 = T1c2;
```

The solution comes down to selecting yet another column from the table to be updated (T1.col2), and specifically the values for which T1.col1 should be updated, then compare each T1.col2 with the previously selected ones.

However the mechanism behind it isn't clear to me, specifically why `update` statement without this edit would update all fields with only one value, so comments are still appreciated.